# How can I call a class method in the same way a UI event handler does?

Tags: python

I'd like to accomplish the following. Imagine the following code in some method of a class (I'm too lazy to write out the whole class).

```
foo = {"A": self.method1,
       "B": self.method2,
       "C": self.method3}

if var in foo.keys():
    foo[var]               # Executes one of the class methods
```

Obviously, this doesn't work otherwise I wouldn't be here asking.

I've tried putting `()` at the end of each dictionary value: `self.method1()`, but this just executes all three methods when foo is created (as I expected).

I've also tried `exec(foo[var])` but that raises TypeError.

Basically I'm trying accomplish the same thing that UI events do. The event is bound in the following way:

```
Bind(event_signal, self.method1)
```

and when event_signal is seen, then the program executes `self.method1(event)`. How can I get my code to call `self.method1()` when `var` is a key in `foo`?

Comment: in python `functions` are just objects, and you `call` them with `(args)`. You're storinga dictionary of objects - as this is what a dictionary does. It just happens that these `objects` are `functions`, and so you just need to `call` them. The same way that you can do `a = range` and then later on do `a(5)` to get `[0,1,2,3,4]`. You just need to call the functions. `foo[var]()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the parentheses at the place in the code where you want to call the method:

```
foo[var]()
```

Note that if the method requires an argument (like `event`), you'll have to pass one by doing `foo[var](event)`.  You'll have to decide what to pass in based on what the method does with that argument.

Comment: Oh man how could I miss that! Thanks a bunch, that's exactly what I wanted.